# How to use np.Vectorize() with Pandas function?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, vectorization, apply

I have the function that operates in Pandas DataFrame format. It works with `pandas.apply()` but it does not work with `np.Vectorize()`. Find the function below:

```
def AMTTL(inputData, amortization = []):
    rate = inputData['EIR']
    payment = inputData['INSTALMENT']
    amount = inputData['OUTSTANDING']
    amortization = [amount]
    if amount - payment <= 0:
        return amortization
    else:
        while amount > 0:
            amount = BALTL(rate, payment, amount)
            if amount <= 0:
                continue
            amortization.append(amount)
    return amortization
```

The function receives `inputData` as Pandas DataFrame format. The `EIR`, `INSTALMENT` and `OUTSTANDING` are the columns name. This function works well with `pandas.apply()`

```
data.apply(AMTTL, axis = 1)
```

However, I have tried to use `np.Vectorize()`. it does not work with the code below:

```
vfunc = np.vectorize(AMTTL)
vfunc(data)
```

It got error like `'Timestamp' object is not subscriptable`. So, I tried to drop other columns that not used but it still got the another error like `invalid index to scalar variable.`

I am not sure how to adjust `pandas.apply()` to `np.Vectorize()`.
Any suggestion? Thank you in advance.

Comment: do not use list as a default argument for a function param, call apply only on the columns you need, i.e `data[['col1', 'col2', 'col3']].apply`

Comment: @AhmadAnis I tried to use np.Vectorize() NOT pd.apply()

Comment: Then use numpy arrays in it to process, `data[['col1', ...,'coln']].values` to pass in numpy array of your dataframe. pass necessary columns only, and modify your function accordingly.

Comment: @AhmadAnis does not work at all!

Comment: can you put the stack trace here

Answer (score 1):

`np.vectorize` is nothing more than a `map` function that is applied to all the elements of the array - meaning you *cannot* differentiate between the columns with in the function. It has no idea of the column names like `EIR` or `INSTALMENT`. Therefore your current implementation for numpy will not work.

From the [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html):

> The vectorized function evaluates pyfunc over successive tuples of the
> input arrays like the python map function, except it uses the
> broadcasting rules of numpy.
>
> The vectorize function is provided primarily for convenience, not for
> performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop.

**Based on your problem, you should try [`np.apply_along_axis`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html) instead, where you can refer different columns with their indexes.**